# Django filter queryset optimization

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filter

I'm using django-filter and i have 40k+ record that comes from filter.

```
def index(request):
            cleaned_objects = Mymodel.objects.filter(is_deleted=False)
            my_objects = ReportFilter(request.GET,queryset=cleaned_objects)
```

and i'm giving some filter for example created_at__gte = 01.01.2011 and this query retrieve 40k records i also using django pagination but i'm getting timeout error. So how can i fix that timeout error and which optimization should i use.

Comment: if you want optimize your `ReportFilter` then you should show its code...

Comment: As @andi said you should definitely provide the code for `ReportFilter`. That said, my guess is that the filter is failing because of the unusual date format, so all results are returned. Try using `2011-01-01` instead.